# How to implement a recursive method in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pointers, recursion

I am currently attempting Exercise 9 in Chapter 9 in "Programming in Objective-C" by Stephen Kochan. Here is a description of the exercise: Define three new classes, called Song, Playlist, and MusicCollection. A Song Object will contain information about a particular song, such as title, artist, album, and playing time. A Playlist will contain the name of the playlist and a collection of songs. A MusicCollection object will contain a collection of playlists, including a special master playlist called library that contains every song in the collection. Define these three classes and write methods to do the following:
-Create a Song object and sets its information
-Create a Playlist object, and add songs to a remove songs from a playlist. A new song should be added to the master playlist if it's not already there. Make sure that if a song is removed from the master playlist, it is removed from all playlists in the music collection as well

Here is my main.m and playlist.m (assume all other files function correctly)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Song.h"
#import "Playlist.h"
#import "MusicCollection.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSString *aTitle = @"Days to Come";
        NSString *aArtist = @"Seven Lions";
        NSString *aAlbum = @"Seven Lions-EP";
        NSString *aPlaytime = @"4:44";
        NSString *bTitle = @"Red Lights";
        NSString *bArtist = @"Tiesto";
        NSString *bAlbum = @"Red Lights";
        NSString *bPlaytime = @"4:24";
        NSString *cTitle = @"Pressure-Alesso Remix";
        NSString *cArtist = @"Nadia Ali";
        NSString *cAlbum = @"Pressure (The Remixes)";
        NSString *cPlaytime = @"6:06";
        NSString *dTitle = @"Neon - Club Mix";
        NSString *dArtist = @"Sander Van Doorn";
        NSString *dAlbum = @"Neon";
        NSString *dPlaytime = @"5:59";
        NSString *eTitle = @"Into the Light";
        NSString *eArtist = @"Mako";
        NSString *eAlbum = @"Into the Light-Single";
        NSString *ePlaytime = @"6:18";

        Song *single1 = [[Song alloc] init];
        Song *single2 = [[Song alloc] init];
        Song *single3 = [[Song alloc] init];
        Song *single4 = [[Song alloc] init];
        Song *single5 = [[Song alloc] init];

        [single1 setTitle: aTitle andArtist: aArtist];
        [single1 setAlbum: aAlbum andTime: aPlaytime];
        [single2 setTitle: bTitle andArtist: bArtist];
        [single2 setAlbum: bAlbum andTime: bPlaytime];
        [single3 setTitle: cTitle andArtist: cArtist];
        [single3 setAlbum: cAlbum andTime: cPlaytime];
        [single4 setTitle: dTitle andArtist: dArtist];
        [single4 setAlbum: dAlbum andTime: dPlaytime];
        [single5 setTitle: eTitle andArtist: eArtist];
        [single5 setAlbum: eAlbum andTime: ePlaytime];

        MusicCollection *myMusic = [[MusicCollection alloc] initWithName: @"myMusic"];

        Playlist *masterplay = [[Playlist alloc] initWithName: @"library"];

        [myMusic addPlaylist: masterplay];

        Playlist *playlist1 = [[Playlist alloc] initWithName: @"Playlist 1"];
        Playlist *playlist2 = [[Playlist alloc] initWithName: @"Playlist 2"];


        [masterplay addSong: single1];
        [masterplay addSong: single2];
        [masterplay addSong: single3];
        [masterplay addSong: single4];
        [masterplay addSong: single5];

        [playlist1 addSong: single3];
        [playlist1 addSong: single4];

        [playlist2 addSong: single5];

        [masterplay list];


    }
    return 0;
}
```

//Here is Playlist.m

```
#import "Playlist.h"


@implementation Playlist

@synthesize playListName, fulllist;

-(id) initWithName: (NSString *) name
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        playListName = [NSString stringWithString: name];
        fulllist = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void) addSong: (Song *) theSong
{        

    if (![fulllist containsObject: theSong])  
    {   
    [fulllist addObject: theSong];
    }

}
-(void) list
{    
    for (Song *theSong in fulllist){
        NSLog (@"%-20s    %-32s", [theSong.title UTF8String], [theSong.artist UTF8String]);
        NSLog (@"%-20s    %-32s", [theSong.album UTF8String], [theSong.playtime UTF8String]);
    }
}

-(void) removeSong: (Song *) theSong
{
    [fulllist removeObjectIdenticalTo:theSong];
}




@end
```

As you can see in main.m I manually add a song to library before I add it to another playlist. How do I change my addSong method so that it automatically adds a song to the library (if it isn't already there) before adding it to another playlist? Similarly how do I change my removeSong method so that it automatically removes a particular song from any playlist if it is removed from library?

Comment: I don't think recursion is the answer to your requirements.

Comment: +1 @HotLicks | I'm also not sure why your putting so much in `main.m`

Comment: @random, it looks like an exercise from a book, so it was probably presented that way to save on code size.

Comment: @random I think alot of the books when learning development of basic foundation based obj c apps, put alot of code in main.

Comment: @danielbeard I don't know why they do that. I remember in college seeing kids put all of their code in main, which I'm sure many of them still do. /rant

Comment: There's certainly nothing wrong with putting test/example code in `main`.  For a test case this large, though, it's usually easier to handle if you break it up a bit more.